# Calling private instance method of parent statically

Tags: php

I've experimented with Late Static Bindings and tried different combinations of using self :: and static :: and then got something really strange. I do not understand how it is possible that the script executes without any warning (error_reporting = E_ALL). Could anyone try to explain how that works?

```
class A {
  private function privateWho() {
    echo __CLASS__.PHP_EOL;
  }
  public function test() {
    B::privateWho();
  }
}

class B extends A {}

$b = new B();
$b->test(); // prints A
```

Comment: What's weird here?

Comment: Yes, what's weird and WHY do you think it's weird?

Comment: You think that's weird. Look at [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d772eda2eb4ee9376a16e5d09af9b47746fb0c9a)

Comment: I don't understand how it is possible to call private method of parent object using scope of B class.

Comment: Plus, I think it should print warining/depricated when I call non-static method statically.

Comment: @bortomar [it does](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) "**Warning** In PHP 7, calling non-static methods statically is deprecated, and will generate an E_DEPRECATED warning. Support for calling non-static methods statically may be removed in the future."

Comment: @William Perron Yes, it does but in my example doesn't.

Comment: I think I read about this before but I may be mistaken. This is a kind of downcasting from parent to child type. At least that's what it looks like. The `::` doesn't seem to denote static call but rather has the same meaning as in `parent::function` in which `::` is used to denote calling the superclass function (which works for static and non static). Would be interesting to find the actual documentation for this.